# Sitecore Alias refuses to work

Tags: sitecore

I've inherited a Sitecore project and added a new alias to a set of existing aliases on an item within the content tree.

However, although I can visit the older aliases any of my new aliases seem not to work and lead to a 404.

I've tried publishing the content items and even System/Aliases however they still refuse to work.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Perhaps. Did you publish the content, your alias points to?

Comment: @MarkCassidy Yes. One of the first things I tried assuming it was that :/

Comment: Try switching over to your Web DB and check if the aliases that you configured appear, as expected. If they do, verify that none of your aliases conflict with/duplicate any other aliases or paths.

Comment: I am assuming that going to the item directly does not respond with a 404?

Comment: I have experienced what @ZacharyKniebel mentions in the past - specifically old duplicates (the result of a create/publish/delete workflow).  Could be worth switching to the web DB and taking a quick look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking the points raised by Zachary Kniebel I finally figured it was down to the scope of the items and how URL are generated.

For example we have:

```
Home/
  Holidays/
    Some Item
```

Now the alias could be `Toads` on `Some Item`. So I assumed the following URL would work:

http://www.example.com/holidays/some-item

http://www.example.com/holidays/toads

However, because aliases are system wide it dawned on me that really the alias was:

http://www.example.com/toads

This means in order to get the structure I wanted I had to create the alias `Holidays/Toads` instead of just `Toads`, replicating the tree structure as needed.

When I did this the aliases started working as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Several things could be preventing your aliases from working, some of which depend on the setup of your system:

1. Verify that your aliases were published. To do this, switch over to your Web DB and check to see if the aliases that you configured appear, as expected. If they are not published, be sure to run a publish on the Aliases folder (I suggest a Republish, just to be safe).

   - If after that your aliases are not working and are still not published, try running a full site Republish.

     - If they still won't publish, move on to number 3, below
   - If your aliases your aliases are not working and are published, try [rebuilding the Link Database](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Articles/Administration/Links%20Database.aspx).

     - If your aliases are still not working, move on to numbers 2 and 4, below
2. Ensure that each alias that you defined is unique. Note that for a multi-site solution, being unique for the context site is not enough - if you have the alias defined for one of the sites and try to define it for the other it will not work - as the alias cannot be used differently for each site.

   - Note that this is the default behavior of Sitecore's *AliasResolver*
   - If necessary, you can customize the *AliasResolver* to allow you to specify a separate alias folder for each site, following [this tutorial](http://sitecoreblog.patelyogesh.in/2013/08/sitecore-item-alias-alternate-url.html) by Yogesh Patel.
3. (skip this if you completed step 1 and were able to publish your aliases successfully) Special Access Rights/Permissions are required in order to configure Sitecore aliases. I highly doubt that this is the issue, as you were clearly able to create alias items, but I am a fan of covering the base-cases first, so I would verify all the same.

   - If you do find that you are missing the necessary permissions and are trying to figure out how to configure them/if you have trouble finding what permissions you need then you should take a look at [this article](http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2013/10/Configure-Access-to-Aliases-Features-in-the-Sitecore-ASPNET-CMS.aspx), by John West.
4. Also unlikely, but possible, is that redirects/rewrites were configured to send you to the 404 page from the URLs you set as aliases (it could be a RegEx that redirects all of the URLs that you tried to provide as aliases). Start by checking out your config files and/or IIS for Rewrites and Redirects. If you do not see anything, then check for redirects.

   - If redirects are your issue, then the Redirect Module is likely to be the culprit. Check if it is installed and configured to redirect your aliases to 404 pages
   - If the Redirect Module is not configured, check for custom redirection in your code

Hopefully this helps. Good luck and happy coding! :)

Comment: I've upvoted this because it gave me some good starting points thankyou.